# Knockout - How to reference clicked element and also pass in parameters

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to click on an element and call a function with a parameter while also keeping track of which element was clicked on.  The examples on Knockout seem to do one or the other, but not both.

On my element I have the following

```
data-bind="click: testFunction.bind($data, 1,2,3)"
```

And the function that I call is defined as follows

```
function(one, two, three, four){
    console.log("1st param: " + one);
    console.log("2nd param: " + two);
    console.log("3rd param: " + three);
    console.log("4th param: " + four);
};
```

The output does not make any sense to me

1st param: 1
2nd param: 2
3rd param: 3
4th param: [object Object]

Where 4th parameter seems to be the entire view model.

How can I have a click binding that can access $event.target while also passing in parameters?

Comment: You don't want to access the click target. \*Jedi mind trick gesture\* Explain what you intend to achieve in the end.

Comment: I want to basically do $(this).toggleClass('active') when it was clicked, in addition to doing stuff with the actual data parameter that I sent in.  But I have no way of accessing $(this).

Comment: There is the `css` binding for this purpose. Don't attempt to access the DOM in your viewmodel, this will inevitably end with shooting yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the commments:

> I want to `basically do $(this).toggleClass('active')` when it was
>   clicked, in addition to doing stuff with the actual data parameter
>   that I sent in. But I have no way of accessing `$(this)`

And you should not have a way to do this. Knockout is about separating your view from your viewmodel, making the view depend *automatically* (!) on viewmodel state. You should never reference your view from within your viewmodel because that would reverse the dependency and ultimately hurt you (because it hampers re-usability and locks down what should be abstract functionality with implementation details)

If you have a state like "active", represent it in your viewmodel with an observable:

```
function SomeViewmodel() {
    var self = this;

    self.isActive = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggleActive = function () {
        self.isActive( !self.isActive() );
    }
}
```

and reference it in your view via the `css` binding:

```
<div data-bind="click: toggleActive, css: {active: isActive}">click me</div>
```

Knockout handles the rest. This way the abstract definition ("this thing is active") is clearly separated from the implementation ("the element representing this thing has a certain CSS class because it is active"). Should you change your mind about how "active" is visually represented, all you need to modify is the view, because the viewmodel is not concerned with it.

And you never need to know the clicked element (nor do you need jQuery to implement it).

Comment: You are right, I was being lazy. I felt it was going to easier this way, but I have done it with css: binding as you suggested and kept the sacred viewmodel the way it should be :)

Comment: @mls It's less about sacred than about doing the wrong thing and doing the right thing. Conveniently, doing the right is actually *easier* here.